# Setting dynamic click and model expressions with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this inside a ng-repeat block:

```
<a href='#' ng-model="collapsed{{$index}}" ng-click="collapsed{{$index}}=!collapsed{{$index}}">{{item.type}}</a>
  <div ng-show="collapsed{{$index}}">
    {{item.type}}
  </div>
```

I need to have each iteration keep track of its own collapsed state.  I get all sorts of errors trying to do the above.  The ng-model doesn't like {{ }}'s, the ng-click doesn't seem to either.  I've also tried [$index] without much luck.

Any ideas on the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you can try to introduce an array of booleans, where it keeps the collapse state of each item in your list.

```
// if every one of them starts off in a collapsed state, all booleans are true
$scope.collapses = [true, true, true, ...];
```

Then it just becomes

```
<a ng-click="toggle($index)">{{item.type}}</a>
<div ng-hide="collapses[$index]">{{item.type}}</div>
```

As for the `toggle()` function:

```
$scope.toggle = function(index) { collapses[index] = !collapses[index]; };
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a lot cleaner to keep track of the collapsed state if you put this into a controller:

Javascript:

```
app.controller('collapseCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.collapsed = true;
    $scope.toggle = function(){
        $scope.collapsed = !$scope.collapsed;
    };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="collapseCtrl">
    <a href='#' ng-click="toggle()">{{item.type}}</a>
    <div ng-show="collapsed">
      {{item.type}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Mine takes place in a ng-repeat loop, where each iteration should be able to be collapsed separately.  So I need a way to track them all.

Comment: Hey, how about something like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZnBmBMuVAogbAiHmkSfK?p=preview